# The grammatical construction of "moments of 20th-century history packaged into an upmarket soap opera"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Bad taste and bad timing combine in the new series of The Crown (Netflix). This was once a superior costume drama, **moments of 20th-century history packaged into an upmarket soap opera**.

[Source](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/tv/0/crown-netflix-season-5-review-royal-dirty-laundry-re-aired-viewing/)

---

1. Does bold part mean "and moments of 20th-century history was packaged into an upmarket soap opera"?
2. What's the grammatical construction of the bold part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is essentially what it means. There are two ways to understand the bold part:

1. It could be considered an appositive, standing in apposition to "a superior costume drama". (Note that a plural appositive may refer to a singular referent; there is no prohibition against that.)
2. It could be considered a nominative absolute. Such a construction typically includes two parts: a nominal phrase and its modifier. In this sentence, "moments of 20th-century history" would be the nominal phrase and "packaged into an upmarket soap opera" would be its modifier. You can read more about this construction in [Wikipedia's article on it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_absolute).

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand your second explanation. In your first explanation, does "moments of 20th-century history packaged into an upmarket soap opera" mean "moments of 20th-century history **which were** packaged into an upmarket soap opera"?

Comment: @Englishgood Yes, that's right. It's sometimes called "[whiz-deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whiz-deletion)", in which a relative pronoun (in this case "which") and a form of "to be" (in this case "were") are deleted.

Comment: I'd like to ask one more question. In your second explanation, does "moments of 20th-century history packaged into an upmarket soap opera" tell us the reason for "this was once a superior costume drama"?

Comment: @Englishgood I suppose that one might infer that the fact that there were "moments of 20th-century history packaged into an upmarket soap opera" explains why "this was once a superior costume drama". It's not entirely clear to me whether that's the actual reason or whether it's just an additional point about the show that the author felt like mentioning.